# Estimating covariance of multimodal distribution from series of samples

Tags: covariance, multinomial-distribution

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, the variables are distributed multimodally.
I want to calculate covariance $Cov(X, Y)$ from a series of batches of data. For example I have a series $X_1 = \{x^1_1, x^1_2 ... x^1_n\}$, $Y_1 = \{y^1_1, y^1_2 ... y^1_n\}$ then $$X_2 = \{x^2_1, x^2_2 ... x^2_n\}, Y_2 = \{y^2_1, y^2_2 ... y^2_n\}$$ $$...$$
$$ X_b = \{x^b_1, x^b_2 ... x^b_n\}, Y_b = \{y^b_1, y^b_2 ... y^b_n\}$$
All of them are non-uniformly samples, so sometimes It will sample one mode, and sometimes another.

The question is how to calculate $Cov(X, Y)$ in this case ? Do I calculate $Cov(X,Y)$ for every batch ($Cov_1, Cov_2 ... Cov_b$) and then average them ? Or maybe I concatenate all of the data and then calculate $CoV(X,Y)$ ? (Where the second method does not seem to me reasonable).

Answer (score 1):

**If I understood the question correctly, both the methods will yield the identical estimate of covariance.**

Suppose you use the $k^{th}$ batch to compute covariance (assuming zero mean)
$$COV_k = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^ky_i^k$$,
and, subsequently, the average of $b$ covariances
$$COV=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{k=1}^{b}COV_k$$
$$COV=\frac{1}{b}\sum_{k=1}^{b}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^ky_i^k$$
$$COV=\frac{1}{nb}\sum_{k=1}^{b}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^ky_i^k$$

Notice that the last equation is your second method of computing the covariance.

Comment: So average over covariances from each batch ?

Comment: Also which mean should I use then, to make mean-free covariance matrix ? Because when I use mean of every individual batch, then the covariance averages to a weird, small value. Should I keep track of population mean and make the variables mean-free so that ?

Comment: First, as I have explained in the answer you can use any of the two methods to compute the covariance. Second, I am guessing it is better to use sample average over all batches as your mean. But it should not make a big difference if $n$ is large enough. I do not understand what you mean by 'weird small value'. Can you explain that a little more and also what is value of $n$ in your example?